# Updating items dynamically when expiry date changes

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of item codes that has to be updated automatically when their dates expires.

There are 3 codes and each code has a different start date and an end date and the time that they must change.

When one code expires it must update automatically and reflect the change in the HTML.

I am kind of lost here and would really appreciate any help!

My current set up is like so:

HTML

```
<p>Lorem ipsum...<span class="itemCode"></span>...fermentum erat.</p>
```

JavaScript

```
function update(){
        var dateList = {
            code:["1234", "5678", "4321"],
            sd:["7/9/2018, 9/10/2018, 11/02/2018"],   // start date
            ed:["9/10/2018, 11/02/2018, 01/20/2019"], //  end date
            time:["6:00AM, 6:00AM, 6:00AM"]
        }
    }
```

And..this is the point where I get stumped..Please Help!

Comment: This doesn't seem to include any questions? What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: I am getting lost on why would you hold statically the expiration date of your products, even if it's just a coding exercise.

Comment: It would be better to perform AJAX calls to check if a code has expired and needs to be changed (which should be done server-side).

Comment: @ZombieChowder each item has a set start date and end date...the first code's start date is today. I statically put the dates in an array to loop through the array and return the right code based on validating the values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this function when the window loads, and have a `setInterval` to continuously check code validity.

```
 window.onload = function(){
   var dateList = {
        code:["1234", "5678", "4321"],
        sd:["7/9/2018, 9/10/2018, 12/05/2018"],   // start date
        ed:["11/12/2018, 1/02/2019, 2/20/2019"], //  end date
        time:["6:00AM, 6:00AM, 6:00AM"]
   }
   var check;
   //setInterval is for continuously checking the validity of the codes
   check = setInterval(function(){
     var codes = dateList.code;
     var enddates = dateList.ed;
     for(var i = 0; i < codes.length; i++){
        var now = new Date();
        now.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        if(enddates[i] < now){
          //change code because it has expired
          dateList.code[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
       }
     }
  }, 1000); //1000 is time in milliseconds
}
```

Comment: thanks for responding with this solution, i really appreciate it. I'm having trouble reflecting this in my HTML. I tried using jQuery and displaying the result like $(".itemCode").html(check);

Comment: @scrippyfingers `check` is the `setInterval` for checking and as such, it should not be used as the `html` of an element. Try `$('.itemCode').html(dateList.code[i])` if you want to display the new code. However, this will make all elements with the `itemCode` class to display the new code, which is probably not what you want. Consider having a `span` with a specific `id` display the code instead.